# CentOS 6.5 fail on install

Tags: linux, centos, centos6.5

I've tried to install centos on my pc and the installer throw the following error:

```
Formatting Failed
An error was encountered while formatting device /dev/sda1
Details: invalid device especification
```

Anyone know if my hardware is the problem, because i have installed the same centos on another pc with intel processor?

```
PC details:
motherboard - gigabyte 970a d3p
processor   - amd athlon II x2 245
ram         - kingston 4GB 1600
hd seagate barracuda 1tb
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with a CPU brand. You get an error when you try to format /dev/sda1 (first disk, first partition). The error mentions an invalid device specification, which probably means that you did not create partition #1.

(Or you created P1, P2, P3, ... and then deleted P1).

if it is not there, it cannot be formatted.